# How to get date values from field collection to a node?

Tags: datetime, entities

I am trying to print the values from a field collection using following code in Drupal 7 node.But the date values are not getting.

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
 $formtype = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_latest_schedules');
 foreach($formtype as $itemid) { 

 $item = field_collection_field_get_entity($itemid);

 print $item->field_course_starts_on['und'][0]['safe_value'];
 print $item->field_course_ends_on['und'][0]['safe_value'];

 }
```

How can i print the date from a filed collection?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `field_course_starts_on` and `field_course_starts_on` are fields that represent date and you want to print it as date. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So you can print those fields as date like:

```
print date('d F, Y', $item->field_course_starts_on['und'][0]['safe_value']);
print date('d F, Y', $item->field_course_ends_on['und'][0]['safe_value']);
```

The part `'d F, Y'` is a date format. Take a look at [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to see all options for format parameter.

### **Update**

First you have to load the ids of the field collection fields of the node:

```
$formtype = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_latest_schedules');

// Extract the field collection item ids
$ids = array_column($formtype, 'value');
foreach ($formtype as $ft_field) {
    $ids[] = $ft_field['value'];
}
```

To iterate over all fields you can use the following code:

```
//Get the entities
$collections = field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids);

//Loop over the array - if you have more than one entity
for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($collections); $i++) {
    $collection = $collections [$i];

    //Iterate over all member vars of the FieldCollectionItemEntity object
    foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
        //Look for fields - there are some other class vars, too.
        if (strpos ($key, 'field') !== false) {
            //Search for textfields 
            if (isset($value['und']) && is_array($value ['und']) && isset($value['und'][0]['value'])) {
                print "Field ".$key." ".$value['und'][0]['value'];
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

And than debug, target wanted fields and print those fields' values.

Comment: i am sorry i tried it and not getting any result.'field_latest_schedules' is my main field name and field type is "field collection".The date fields inside the collections are 'field_course_starts_on' and 'field_course_ends_on' .The manage display type is plain.and i am using the above code to print the values.But date is not coming.How can i print it?

Comment: Do you get any output when you print those two fields as you do and what do you get?

Comment: I think on output without date function (your originally code), what you get as output?

Comment: print $item->field_course_starts_on['und'][0]['safe_value'] ;
 this shows empty result...

Comment: I update my answer...

Comment: no hope still not working...

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me....thanks for the helps....

```
<?php

if (isset($content['field_latest_schedules']['#items'])) {

    foreach ($node->field_latest_schedules['und'] as $key => $value) {
    $field_collection = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($value['value']));
    $idx = $value['value'];

    print $field_collection[$idx]->field_course_starts_on['und'][0]['value'];
    print $field_collection[$idx]->field_course_ends_on['und'][0]['value'];
}
?>
```